# How do I stop Javascript form validate submitting before json response has returned?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I have an html form that is validated by Javascript, but since connecting to an external API the form submits before the API queries have returned

All of the alerts are triggering correctly, however the last line of code - if (rtn) {
                $('#saleForm')[0].submit();
            } -
is resolving before the api call data returns and therefore once I accept the alerts the form always submits (as rtn is always true).

I am using setTimeout to wait for the return in the two if() blocks, and have tried a do/whilst loop around submit but that didn't work.

Is there a method I can use to force the submit to wait until all the previous conditions have been checked, before if(rtn)?

```
    $('#saleForm').off('submit').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var rtn = true;

    if (window.hasIntegration == 'no' && $('#eventDate').val() == '') {
          alert('Please choose the event date and time.');
          $('#eventDate').focus();
          return false;
        }

    $('.itemValue').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            alert('Please ensure all values are entered.');
            $('#ticket-rows').focus();
            rtn = false;
        }
    });

    if (!$('#terms').is(':checked')) {
        alert('Please accept the terms and conditions.');
        return false;
    }

// now use  integration to validate user supplied details

    if (window.integrationId == 2) {
        window.foundApiSellerDetails = [];
        window.sellerEmailMatch = [];
        var apiShowSelected = document.getElementById("showDateTime");
        var apiShowId = apiShowSelected.value;
        var orderRefField = document.getElementById('order_reference');
        var orderRef = orderRefField.value;

        $.get('/' + id + '/api-seller-details/' + apiShowId + '/' + orderRef, function(data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                window.foundApiSellerDetails = 'yes';

                $.each( data.result, function( key, value ) {
                    var apiOrderId = value.order.id;
                    var apiBuyerEmail = value.buyer.email;
                    var apiOrderToken = value.token;

                    $.get('/get-seller-email', function(data) {
                        if (apiBuyerEmail === data) {
                            window.sellerEmailMatch = 'yes';
                        } else {
                            window.sellerEmailMatch = 'no';
                        }

                    });
                });
            } else {
                window.foundApiSellerDetails = 'no';
            }

        });

        setTimeout(function(){
            if (window.foundApiSellerDetails == 'no') {
                alert('Sorry, we can\'t find any details with Order Reference ' + orderRef + '. Please check your order number  or contact);
                $('#order_reference').focus();
                return false;
            }

            if (window.foundApiSellerDetails == 'yes' && window.sellerEmailMatch == 'no') {
                alert('Sorry, your email doesn\'t match the buyers email for this order');
                return false;
            }

        }, 1000);

    }
        if (rtn) {
            $('#saleForm')[0].submit();
        }

});
```

Comment: Call the submit function from the validation function after it's finished. That's how you'd generally do it.

Comment: Ajax has a function of to declare whether it should act in async or not. Wait for the JSON to return before continuing or not. Maybe what you are looking for here. I am not sure how you could use it here, but i could show you my ajax code if you like, utilizing this?

Comment: Make a submit function that takes an event as an argument and call `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody! I have brought the submit function inside the setTimeout function, and then brought that whole block inside the $.get api call as per @Gendarme. I've also added else after the if integration == 2, to make the submit work if no integration exists. New code below. Works a treat now.

```
// now use  integration to validate user supplied details

if (window.integrationId == 2) {
    window.foundApiSellerDetails = [];
    window.sellerEmailMatch = [];
    var apiShowSelected = document.getElementById("showDateTime");
    var apiShowId = apiShowSelected.value;
    var orderRefField = document.getElementById('order_reference');
    var orderRef = orderRefField.value;

    $.get('/' + id + '/api-seller-details/' + apiShowId + '/' + orderRef, function(data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            window.foundApiSellerDetails = 'yes';

            $.each( data.result, function( key, value ) {
                var apiOrderId = value.order.id;
                var apiBuyerEmail = value.buyer.email;
                var apiOrderToken = value.token;

                $.get('/get-seller-email', function(data) {
                    if (apiBuyerEmail === data) {
                        window.sellerEmailMatch = 'yes';
                    } else {
                        window.sellerEmailMatch = 'no';
                    }

                });
            });
        } else {
            window.foundApiSellerDetails = 'no';
        }

    setTimeout(function(){
        if (window.foundApiSellerDetails == 'no') {
            alert('Sorry, we can\'t find any details with Order Reference ' + orderRef + '. Please check your order number  or contact);
            $('#order_reference').focus();
            return false;
        }

        if (window.foundApiSellerDetails == 'yes' && window.sellerEmailMatch == 'no') {
            alert('Sorry, your email doesn\'t match the buyers email for this order');
            return false;
        }

    if (rtn) {
        $('#saleForm')[0].submit();
    }

    }, 1000);

});

} else {
    if (rtn) {
        $('#saleForm')[0].submit();
    }
}

});
```